# Loading page error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a custom loading page based on following progress bar code.

```
    document.onreadystatechange = function(e)
{
  if(document.readyState=="interactive")
  {
    var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) 
    {
      set_ele(all[i]);
    }
  }
}

function check_element(ele)
{
  var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
  var totalele=all.length;
  var per_inc=100/all.length;

  if($(ele).on())
  {
    var prog_width=per_inc+Number(document.getElementById("progress_width").value);
    document.getElementById("progress_width").value=prog_width;
    $("#bar1").animate({width:prog_width+"%"},10,function(){
      if(document.getElementById("bar1").style.width=="100%")
      {
          $("#about1").show();
      }         
    });
  }

  else  
  {
    set_ele(ele);
  }
}

function set_ele(set_element)
{
  check_element(set_element);
}
```

I have kept this loading page code on the top (1st line in head tag) along its HTML. 
**But it is not giving me the loading effect.Like the whole page appears along with loading page with 100% progress bar when all the content (images, HTML and imported files) are loaded.**

Please help me. **If you need to see working demo go to www.scratchcoder.com**

Comment: It's loading using your url. What's the problem with that?

Comment: are you running this code even before you load JQuery ?

Comment: Please share the HTML too. We need to see if all the used ID and classes are available or not. There might be some obvious error.

Comment: You can visit this running code on www.scratchcoder.com